# How to combine different rows of a dataframe accessing them through the name of a factor that is in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two variables, the first variable are factors and the second are numerical. I want to sum several rows based on the name of the factor in that row.

I want the result of the sum to be stored in the row that had a higher value at the beginning and to delete the rest of the rows that have been added. The dataframe is ordered. How could I get something like that?

For example:

```
I have:                         I want:

Things     Numbers             Things     Numbers

Bottle       35                 Bottle       35
Pencil       27                 Paper        32
Paper        24                 Pencil       29
Pen          13                 Pen          13
Phone        10                 Phone        10
Apple         9                 Apple        9
Chair         7
Bus           2
Kitchen       1
```

```
Paper=Paper+Chair+Kitchen
Pencil=Pencil+bus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Things, ~Numbers,
   "Bottle",       35,
   "Pencil",       27,
    "Paper",       24,
      "Pen",       13,
    "Phone",       10,
    "Apple",        9,
    "Chair",        7,
      "Bus",        2,
  "Kitchen",        1
  )

df %>%

  # might have to convert to character first...
  # mutate(Things = as.character(Things)) %>%

  mutate(
    Things = case_when(
      Things %in% c("Paper", "Chair", "Kitchen") ~ "Paper",
      Things %in% c("Pencil", "Bus") ~ "Pencil",
      TRUE ~ Things
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(Things) %>%
  summarise(
    Numbers = sum(Numbers)
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(Numbers))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   Things Numbers
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 Bottle      35
#> 2 Paper       32
#> 3 Pencil      29
#> 4 Pen         13
#> 5 Phone       10
#> 6 Apple        9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>